# uno platform: gridview landscape images not showing in grid on earlier android

Tags: gridview, uno-platform

My app has a `GridView` with a `ItemWidth`, `ItemHeight` are determined during a `SizeChanged` event. Inside each cell I have a Grid containing an Image. So, net result, I should have a `GridView` with an array of fixed sized images. This works on UWP and Android API 29.

However for two earlier Android APIs, only some of the images display.

The GridView has this data template (I removed some other elements from the interior Grid to simplify the problem):

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageItemTemplate">
    <Grid Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,1"  Background="PowderBlue">

      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"  />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding FileName}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```

That data template is used here:

```
<Grid>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />  <!-- title bar-->
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />  <!-- grid -->
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <controls:Titlebar ... />

  <GridView Grid.Row="2"
    x:Name = "DetailGrid"
    Margin="0"
    Padding="0"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"
    ItemsSource = "{x:Bind DetailGridItems}"
    ItemTemplateSelector = "{StaticResource DetailItemSelector}"
    SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">

    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid  Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
  </GridView>

</Grid>
```

And, in case you want to see the resize code:

```
private void OnSizeChanged (object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
  ItemsWrapGrid panel = ((ItemsWrapGrid)gridView.ItemsPanelRoot);

  const int minColWidth = 250;
  var columns = System.Math.Ceiling(ActualWidth / minColWidth);
  double newWidth = e.NewSize.Width / columns;
  panel.ItemWidth = newWidth;
  panel.ItemHeight = newWidth;
}
```

Here are some screenshots:

Android API 29
[image]

Android API 23
[image]

Android API 21
[image]

Comment: It seems that we are using something that is not supported on those previous versions. Can you report this on Uno GitHub please?

Comment: Done: https://github.com/vskotatko/MinGridView/issues/1